# Is this json_object() function creating a circular reference? (in bitcoin mining)

Tags: c, json, jansson

This question is about what the role of the function `json_object()` used in [cpumier](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer/blob/master/cpu-miner.c#L742)

I will show cpuminer code first and Jansson documentation second:

FIRST:

```
else if (work->txs) {
        char *req;

        for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(work->data); i++)
            be32enc(work->data + i, work->data[i]);
        bin2hex(data_str, (unsigned char *)work->data, 80);
        if (work->workid) {
            char *params;
            val = json_object();  //   ============>>>>>>   MY QUESTION !!!!! - THE PROBLEM IS HERE
            json_object_set_new(val, "workid", json_string(work->workid));      // AND HERE
            params = json_dumps(val, 0);
            json_decref(val);
            req = malloc(128 + 2*80 + strlen(work->txs) + strlen(params));
            sprintf(req,
                "{\"method\": \"submitblock\", \"params\": [\"%s%s\", %s], \"id\":1}\r\n",
                data_str, work->txs, params);
            free(params);
```

SECOND: Read [Jansson Documentation](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.8/apiref.html):

> Circular References
>
> A circular reference is created when an object or an array is,
> directly or indirectly, inserted inside itself. The direct case is
> simple:

```
json_t *obj = json_object();
json_object_set(obj, "foo", obj);
```

I have tried to find what `json_object()` is doing there in the cpuminer but I am not even sure whether `json_object()` is a circular reference or not.

Please explain json_object() function.

Comment: Please include the language tag into your question.